# iOS: How to intercept touch event before UI element handle the event

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In an iOS app, I press a button, then a popup menu shows.
I want the popup menu being closed if I touch anywhere(a `UITableView`, other `UIButton`) in the screen outside of the menu.
How can I intercept the touch event before the UI element(like `UITableView`, `UIButton`) on the screen handle the event, so I can close the menu programmatically?

I have tried `-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in `UIViewController`, but it does not work. The UI element I touched will handle the event so I cannot intercept the event.

Answer (score 3):

Add a transparent `UIView` covering your whole screen under the menu. Then handle only the taps to this view.

Answer (score 0):

Set `userInterActionEnabled` Property of all views to `NO` while the menu is visible. Once discarded, set it to YES again.

```
- (void) enableOrDisableControlsExceptMenu : (UIView *) parentView :(bool) bEnabled
{
    for (UIView * view in parentView.subviews)
    {
       if (![view isKindOfClass:[YourMenu class])   //YourMenu is the menu view class
           view.userInterActionEnabled = bEnabled;
       [self enableOrDisableControlsExceptMenu : view :bEnabled];
    }
}
```

When the menu is visible, call the above method like:

```
[self enableOrDisableControlsExceptMenu:self.view :NO];
```

When the menu is discarded (invisible), call it like:

```
[self enableOrDisableControlsExceptMenu:self.view :YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to the main window and intercept the touch. If all you want is a tap then `UITapGestureRecognizer` should do the job.

If you are looking for any kind of touch then I would recommend using a custom GestureRecognizer which implements `touchesBegan`.